# Multiple ion-checkbox, same formControlName

Tags: ionic-framework, angular7, ionic4

I have an Angular Reactive from with multiple `ion-checkboxes` with the same`formControlName` but they are not kept in sync when one is checked/unchecked.

```
<ion-item lines="none">
    <ion-label color="dark">Client</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox formControlName="client" (click)="clientToggle()" slot="end"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

---

```
public clientToggle() {
    this.cubeForm.controls.client.setValue(!this.cubeForm.controls.client.value);
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed the html to:

```
<ion-checkbox formControlName="client [checked]="cubeForm.controls['client'].value" slot="end"></ion-checkbox>
```